# Problem Using Ruby Version Manager (RVM) on Mac

Tags: ruby, rvm

I just started reading Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial. He recommends using the latest version of Ruby, currently 1.9.2. My Mac, an original Intel iMac now running Snow Leopard, has Ruby 1.8.7 installed.

Michael suggests installing the latest versions of Ruby and and Rails using the Ruby Version Manager (RVM). So I went to the RVM site and installed RVM with...

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

It seemed to work. A message popped up in the Terminal thanking me for using RVM.

Following Michael's next instruction, which is to make sure RVM is current:

```
rvm update --head
```

which results in `-bash: rvm: command not found`

A footnote suggests that I might need to install Subversion, so installed it, but I still get the same error message when I run `rvm update --head`.

Any suggestions? I'd really like to move beyond setup and get to building my Rails app.

Comment: A really good, and important, step after installing RVM is `rvm notes`, which will show the recommended dependencies for the OS you are running. If you run that and follow the directions for what files are needed, subsequent installations of Ruby will go a lot more smoothly and should work as expected. This applies to all platforms RVM runs on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rvm` also gave a message after install saying you needed to add a line to your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent):

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

do that, and then type `. ~/.bashrc` or open a new terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your help Peter. I actually don't see any reference to that in the message I get after installing RVM.

How do I open my ~/.bashrc (or equivalent) so that I can add this line?

Comment: When I put `~/.bashrc` into Terminal I get the following error... -bash: /Users/Eddie/.bashrc: No such file or directory

Comment: RVM automatically adds it to `.bash_profile`, but some systems don't use that file, so it never gets included from `.bashrc` so the RVM initializer doesn't get called. To fix it I confirm that's what the problem is, and if so, I'll append that line to my `.bashrc` and remove it from `.bash_profile`, or trash that file.